# Integrate Python code from Spring Boot project

Tags: java, python, jython, jython-2.7

I have python code. I run it using `python -m base-package arguments`

I want to run this project from a spring boot project and use the output given by the python. I could not find any simple tutorial, is there any simple way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Try execute your command with this:

```
    private String getResponseFromCommand(String command) throws IOException {
        Process process = exec(command);
        InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        String response = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in))
                .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

I wrote this for running docker commands and getting feedback from them. It should work for any command though.